# Get value from php array that have the same key name

Tags: php, arrays

a quick answer about how to get the value (and pass it in a php variable) from an array:

i've this array:

```
$array = array(
            array('name' => 'infotel', 'value' => '+39080123456' ), 
            array('name' => 'location', 'value' => 'Bari')
            );
```

I need to pass the "value" of "infotel" in a $telephone variable, and the "value" of "location" in a $city variable.

how can i solve this trouble? thanks

Comment: Try
`$telephone = $array[0]['name'];`
`$location = $array[1]['name'];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a function for that.

```
function custom_search($search_for='',$search_in=array())
{
  if($search_for=='' OR empty($search_in)) return '';
    foreach($search_in as $val)
    {
       if($val['name']==$search_for) {return $val['value'];}
    }
  return '';
}
$telephone=custom_search("infotel",$array);
```

Comment: Don't forget the `location` part of his question as-well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I might do it using the new [**array_column()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)(*requires PHP >= 5.5*) and [**array_walk()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

The good 'ol foreach loop should be fine, or you could just pull them out directly assuming you know what is in the array all the time. But here's something I think is a little fancier ;) ...

```
$arr = array_column($array, 'value', 'name');

array_walk($arr, function(&$v, $k) use (&$telephone, &$city){
    if ($k == 'infotel') $telephone = $v;
    elseif ($k == 'location') $city = $v;
});

echo $telephone; //+39080123456
echo $city;      //Bari
```

[**See Demo - *updated updated updated***](http://3v4l.org/j9lvD)

Comment: prettier answer i should have up voted too but when no results are matched in array it will give `Undefined index: telephone` and `Undefined index: city`. initializing like this can solve the issues `$result = array('telephone'=>'','city'=>'');`  :)

Comment: @karanthakkar Your observation sparked a whole series of changes, from which I think I have improved the function greatly. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help mark :) i guess i need to upgrade to `>5.5` :) +1 for a better edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$telephone='';
$location='';
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{
   if($v['name']=="infotel") 
   {
     $telephone=$v['value'];
     break;
   }
   if($v['name']=="location") 
   {
     $location=$v['value'];
     break;
   }
}
echo $telephone; 
echo $location;
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only this array, use:

```
$tel = $array[0]['value'];
$loc = $array[1]['value'];
```

Comment: thanks, but array was dinamically generated, and I can't know if the offset [0] is always tel.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    array('name' => 'infotel', 'value' => '+39080123456' ),
    array('name' => 'location', 'value' => 'Bari')
);

$telephone = $array[0]['value'];
$city = $array[1]['value'];
echo $telephone;

echo $city;
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desire result by using this code. you need not to worry about array keys. but last key will replace your location and telephone value.

```
$array = array(
            array('name' => 'infotel', 'value' => '+39080123456' ), 
            array('name' => 'location', 'value' => 'Bari')
            );
$key1 = '';
$key2 = '';
foreach($array as $k => $a){
    if(array_search('infotel', $a) != false){
        $key1 = $k;
    }
    if(array_search('location', $a) != false){
        $key2 = $k;
    }
}
echo 'telephone = '.$array[$key1]['value'];
echo 'location = '.$array[$key2]['value'];
```